# two-sum algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Below code checks if the sum of any pairs of numbers on an array equals to zero. I'm trying to workout the complexity by considering how many times major operations such as variable declarations, value assignments, comparisons, increments, array accesses etc. Normally the complexity would be O(N^2) but I'm very confused when I have to consider the operations specified above. How should I approach this?

```
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
for(int j=i+1; j<N; j++)
if(a[i] + a[j] == 0)
count++;
```

Comment: Do you need big O complexity or exact complexity?

Comment: I have the big O complexity it's O(N^2).

Comment: If you sort both arrays (O(N log N)), you will be able to check the sums in O(N) time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to indent the code and highlight each operation explicitly:

```
int count = 0; // <-- 1 operation

for(int i=0; i<N; i++) // <-- 2 operations per iteration
    for(int j=i+1; j<N; j++) // <-- 2 operations per iteration
        if(a[i] + a[j] == 0) // <-- 4 operations
            count++; // <-- impossible to tell without knowing a. Counting as 1 operation
```

Here is how you would compute the total number of operations:

[image]

That expression simplifies to:

[image]

Which is your answer. Note that this is O(N^2), which is consistent with your earlier observation.